UseSerilog vs AddSerilog: any functional difference in an asp.net application?
I have created a project to test serilog, nlog and log4net at the same time being unaware that depending on what you do this might not work and discovered in fact that calling UseSerilog would not make a following call to UseNLog work as expected. Differently from what is said here my experience is that if you add other logging providers via the builder.Logging collection after having called UseSerilog, these loggers are called just as well. What I do not understand is if in an asp.net application, from a functional point of view, adding serilog or nlog via UseSerilog and UseNLog respectively is the same than adding them via a call to builder.Logging.AddSerilog and builder.Logging.AddNLog and if there is any side-effect.

This question is similar to: What is the difference between AddSerilog and UseSerilog in .NET 6 Web API?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I myself provided a link to that thread :) have you seen it in my post? Have you read my post till the end?

Use UseSerilog / UseNLog if you want full control over the logging system and prefer to manage everything through Serilog or NLog.Use builder.Logging.AddSerilog / AddNLog if you want Serilog or NLog to complement the default logging system without fully replacing it.

@Rena would you comment a bit more on the "full control" maybe not using a comment but an answer?

Hi @whatever, full control means fully replacing the default logging pipeline in asp.net core.  And the side effect is also full control if you want to use the built-in logging infrastructure like Console, Debug, etc.
